# How to get table definition of a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms, dd

I'm new to SQL Server. There are a couple of tables that in my team's database that we need to replicate. I was wondering if it's possible to get the DDL of the tables. Like for a specific table, get its "CREATE TABLE ...." definition???

I tried going to the Object Explorer -> right clicking the table and selecting Properties, but this doesn't give what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close :)  From management studio

- right click on the table you want
- script table as
- create to
- new query editor window

And there you go!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replicate the SQL needed to generate a table, right-click on the table in the Object Explorer and choose "Script Table As..." and select either "Drop To...", "Create To..." or "Drop and Create To..." and "New Query Window".  Note that this feature also works on most every node in SSMS.  Indexes, for example, can be scripted to a query window, as can constraint, triggers, etc.

Another way to get quick information about a table while writing a query in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) is to highlight a table name in a query window and press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.  Schema information appears in the query results window and includes columns, identity information, indexes, constraints, and foreign key references to this table.